# Create a button to toggle between Fahrenheit and Celsius

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet with yearly temperatures and other weather data for a specific area and I am trying to figure out how to create a macro assigned to a button that changes all the temperatures from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa.

Comment: It's good that you are trying. Please do show what you have tried so we can help fix it.

Comment: Not really sure where to start. I'm not sure if I need to write a subroutine, or record a macro.

Comment: Why not just add a second column to show values in Fahrenheit and Celsius all the time?

Answer (score 0):

If your really want a button then I suggest changing tags but this is possible without, though in two steps. Insert `1.8` and `32` in two separate cells. If to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit copy `1.8` and Paste Special over the relevant cells with Operation Multiply, then copy `32` and repeat with Operation Add. For Fahrenheit to Celsius subtract and divide instead.